# Flow of creating instance using GWT.Create and UI-Binder

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I was going through the code of our GWT application. And got stuck at below piece of code.

```
private static TestEditorUiBind uiBinder = GWT.create(TestEditorUiBind.class);

interface TestEditorUiBind extends UiBinder<Widget,TestEditorViewImpl> {}
```

These are the starting 2 lines of my class. And after this we are creating our GWT Widget using `uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);`

I know that `GWT.create` will create an instance of `TestEditorUiBind` at run time.

But i don't understand why we have declare `TestEditorUiBind` interface on 2nd line and used that on 1st line in `GWT.create`? (I have checked that `TestEditorUiBind` is not declared anywhere else in the application)

Please correct me if i understood something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Due to how the Java language works, the order of the lines does not matter - a new type (enum, interface, class) declared *within* another type actually becomes its own type and doesn't need to wait to be declared within that owner type. It looks like these two lines of code both exist in `TestEditorViewImpl.java` - assuming so, the java compiler will actually create two compiled bytecode files:

- `TestEditorViewImpl.class`
- `TestEditorViewImpl$TestEditorUiBind.class`

The first line then just asks for an instance of `TestEditorViewImpl$TestEditorUiBind`, where ever it happened to have been declared.

So yes, this static field is likely the only place in the project which will use that type, since it is specific to binding the `.ui.xml` to this class. A singleton can be used, since this binder will have no state, but will just populate fields within `TestEditorViewImpl` based on what it found in the `.ui.xml` file.